# map[string]*type "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, amazon-guardduty

When i try to access the struct field i got an error

> invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference.
> gdreport/main.go:30 +0x1e6

i have no clue about the error:

here is my code:

```
var strPtr []*string

var findingId []string = []string{"findingid"}

strPtr = aws.StringSlice(findingId)

maxResult := int64(8)

condition := map[string]*guardduty.Condition{}
condition["id"].Equals = strPtr
```

> line 30 condition["id"].Equals = strPtr

aws sdk for golang
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/guardduty/#Condition type

Comment: `condition["id"]` returns `nil`, because you created an empty `map` just a line above. Then you try to dereference it to read its `.Equals` field, hence you get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

Because `condition` is the empty `map` of `pointers`, you get `nil` value of `*guardduty.Condition` from `condition`.

According [Go maps in action](https://blog.golang.org/maps):

> A two-value assignment tests for the existence of a key:
>
> ```
> i, ok := m["route"]
> ```
>
> In this statement, the first value (i) is assigned the value stored under the key "route". If that key doesn't exist, i is the value type's zero value (0). The second value (ok) is a bool that is true if the key exists in the map, and false if not.

Change your code snippet to

```
if cond, ok := condition["id"]; !ok { // <nil> false
    log.Println("Pointer is null")
} else {
    // Init new guardduty.Condition
    // and assign to required key
    nc := &guardduty.Condition{Equals:strPtr}
    condition["id"] = nc
}
```